# access NSMutableDictionary value without key?

Tags: ios, json, nsdictionary

quite new to iOS development and objective-c at the same time. I have the following method:

```
-(NSMutableArray *)fetchDatabaseJSON{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.ios.com/ios/responseScript.php"];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:NULL error:&error];
    //jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
    //NSLog(@"Array: %@",[jsonArray objectAtIndex:0]);
    jsonDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
    NSLog(@"Dictionary:  %@", jsonDictionary);
    return jsonArray;
}
```

Now the NSLog shows this:

> 2013-02-03 19:15:37.081 TestConnection[24510:c07] Dictionary:  (
>       Bannana,
>       Apple,
>       SomeCheese )

From what I understand that whatever is inside the dictionary doesn't have key-value. How can this be? and how can I fix it? I want to be able to have keys to ease operations on dictionary.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

`JSONObjectWithData` may return an NSArray or NSDictionary, depending on the JSON data you give it. If your JSON string is an array, you will have an NSArray. If your JSON data is a dictionary, you will get an NSDictionary.

Convert your JSON data (your `data` variable) to string and print it out with NSLog. To convert NSData to NSString, use something like:

```
NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:myData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

If you print it out and see a JSON array, you simply don't have a dictionary there.. If you can alter the server-code that generates the JSON, you may be able to change that.

One more thing I noticed, you assume that the returning container is mutable. If I'm not mistaken, you need to use an option like `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers` in the options parameter of JSONObjectWithData to get that.

One last tip, if you want to check in code if you have an NSArray (or NSDictionary), use something like:

```
if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {...}
```